# Visual Studio 2019 Typescript Custom Item Template

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a Custom Item Template in Visual Studio 2019, I tried starting with exporting an existing file in my project using `Project->Export Template` and left all the defaults as is. But no matter where the file was copied to it doesn't show up in `Solution Explorer->Context Menu->Add->New Item` I searched through all the groups and it didn't show up.
I found a couple of other questions regarding this but none of them seemed to work.

[Custom ItemTemplate does not appear in Visual Studio 2015 Add New Item dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295432/custom-itemtemplate-does-not-appear-in-visual-studio-2015-add-new-item-dialog)

[Custom ItemTemplate not showing up in Visual Studio 2010 - Add New Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325950/custom-itemtemplate-not-showing-up-in-visual-studio-2010-add-new-item)

I figured using a working template would work so I copied a template from

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\JavaScript\Code\tsxfile`

to

`C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ItemTemplates\JavaScript\Code\reactComponent` and modified it.

### reactFuncComp.vstemplate

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>React Function Component</Name>
    <Description>React Function Component</Description>
    <Icon Package="{2ffe45c4-5c73-493c-b187-f2e955ff875e}" ID="3"></Icon>
    <TemplateID>ReactFunctionComponent.tsxfile</TemplateID>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
    <DefaultName>reactComponent.tsx</DefaultName>
    <!-- TypeScript project capability is applicable to all JavaScript projects -->
    <!-- "ShowByDefault = false" is needed for the "AppliesTo" to apply the condition(s) to projects that don't restrict specific templates -->
    <ProjectType>JavaScript</ProjectType>
    <ShowByDefault>false</ShowByDefault>
    <AppliesTo>JavaScript</AppliesTo>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" ItemType="TypeScriptCompile" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.tsx" ReplaceParameters="true">reactFuncComp.tsx</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

### reactFuncComp.tsx

---

```
import * as React from "react";

export const $safeitemname$: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    ); 
}

export default $safeitemname$;
```

I double checked that the template location was right, under `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Locations` and it is pointing to

`C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ItemTemplates`

I also tried copying the new template to the location that I copied it from

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\JavaScript\Code\reactFuncComp`

and still nothing, is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got this to show up, I noticed that there was another folder that contained other templates, I started with copying

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\AspNetCore\Web\Scripts\1033\TypeScriptJsxFile` to

`C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ItemTemplates\ReactFunctionComponent`

and modified it. I believe I was missing the template group ID:

`<TemplateGroupID>AspNetCore</TemplateGroupID>`

### reactFuncComp.vstemplate

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>React Function Component</Name>
    <Description>React Function Component template file</Description>
    <Icon Package="{2ffe45c4-5c73-493c-b187-f2e955ff875e}" ID="3"></Icon>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <TemplateGroupID>AspNetCore</TemplateGroupID>
    <TemplateID>ReactFunctionComponent</TemplateID>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>3</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
    <DefaultName>reactComp.tsx</DefaultName>
    <SortOrder>1</SortOrder>
    <ShowByDefault>false</ShowByDefault>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.tsx" ReplaceParameters="true">reactFuncComp.tsx</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

### reactFuncComp.tsx

---

```
import * as React from "react";

export const $safeitemname$: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    ); 
}

export default $safeitemname$;
```